# Error when setting up a project in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am not able to run my project as I am getting these :

> **Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\test-project/protected/config/main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test-project\framework\base\CApplication.php on line 133
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test-project/protected/config/main.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\test-project\framework\base\CApplication.php on line 133**

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you checked if `main.php` exists? Or we shall do it for you?

Comment: main.php file exists there in the config folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice the forward and back slashes in your path.

`C:\xampp\htdocs\test-project/protected/config/main.php`

for windows always use backslashes or use the PHP pre-defined constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

Comment: Thanks adamS. I've also noticed it. But I am not getting, from where the path is getting set or from where the file is getting called. In the line 133 of CApplication.php file the code is as : $config=require($config);

Comment: The slashes are not the problem. Windows accepts both forward and backward slashes. Even if you combine them it will work.

Comment: Is this a permission related problem ? if it is then how and what permission should I provide to the protected folder ?